# Getting infinite loop when want to terminate it with a character like | in c++

Tags: c++

So this is the code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b;
    while(true){
        cout<<"Enter the value of a and b ";
        cin>>a>>b;
        if(a=='|'||b=='|')
            break;
        else
            cout<<"The value of a is "<<a<<"\nThe value of b is "<<b<<endl;
    }
}
```

and the question is  Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered.

When i enter input like | it prints infinitely "The value of a is and value of b is ". What is the reason for this?`enter code here`

Comment: `a` and `b` are integers, `|` is not an integer.

Comment: Never use same variables to possibly store 2 diffrent data types. Is this some kind of homework? Really bad to make you do it that way. If you expect both characters and number I would go with `std::string` and check whether a user has input a number (and then change a string input to int) or a character (then check if the character is `|`)

Comment: The value of `'|'` is its character code. 124 in ASCII. So your program will exit when you type `124`.

Comment: @Barmar this was not the question. The task, I believe, was to terminate the program when `|` is entered. User is expected to input exactly `|`, not the value of that character in ASCII

Comment: @Fureeish I know, I was just telling him how his program actually works.

Comment: @Barmar I would disagree now. You just told him what is the ASCII code of `|` character. You neither explained why the loop goes infinite nor why when entering a `|` character the ASCII value of it is not given to `int` by `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

Your istream operator >> `as_int` is failing and really doing nothing so your loop just keeps going. Either input as chars and convert to ints with checks, or or check the stream for errors.

```
cin>>a>>b;
if( cin.fail( ) )
    break;
```

[istream reading after failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151597/istream-reading-after-failure)

**Additionally:** If you had have traced into the istream operator you would have seen why it was not blocking, that it had failed. Always trace when something is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

std::cin (and I think all streams) by default will set an error flag when you try to read into an invalid data type (e.g. here with trying to read a char into an int variable) and that flag will prevent other std::cin to run until the flag is cleared. To rest the stream, use std::cin.clear() to the reset the error flag and then you have to remove the bad input, either through std::cin.ignore() or read into a string buffer or something, from the stream as it will still be there.